# Display items from a List 10 string items at a time

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, list, foreach

Hello people I need help please. Here's my code.

In here is a list of strings. Let say there are 100 string in the list.

For now in my code it can display 1 item at a time to a richtextbox using foreach, but I want it to display 10 items at a time.

NOTE: This code is in a foreach statement also. so when th 10 items is displayed it must be clear out before new 10 items comes in again to the richtextbox.

What is your good solution for that?

```
 //foreach (string str in links)
 //{


 Scanner scanner = new Scanner();
 List<string> query = scanner.Parse(parts);
 foreach (string item in query)
 {
     richTextBox6.Invoke((Action)(() => richTextBox6.Text = item)); 
 }


//}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the AppendText method on the RichTextBox:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner();
List<string> query = scanner.Parse(parts);
foreach (string item in query)
{
     richTextBox6.Invoke((Action)(() => richTextBox6.AppendText(item))); 
}
```

Comment: +1 for this reply because I'can't understand why the downvote: AppendText is the correct way in appending text to a richbox

Comment: @FelicePollano - thanks Felice, but after re-reading the question, I'm actually not clear on OP's intent, so maybe I jumped the gun a little bit.

Comment: Hi. I have added a note in my question. The AppendText is displaying the 10 items but when new 10 items comes in, the old 10 items stays and the new 10 items were added and so on..

Answer (score 3):

You can use LINQ and use Skip and Take, so Skip(10), Take(10), then you can parse your logic that way.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386988.aspx

Comment: Hi. this will skip some items? I want to display the 100 items by 10 each time with no skipping.

Comment: Well, you could use it to only display 10 at a time, and then if you are navigating with arrows or something, you can "skip" the ones you have already shown, and then show the next 10. So if you are clearing out your text box, you can clear it on each loop, and then calculate how are you are so like i * 10 to determine the "skip"